# Base64 encoding with '\0'

Tags: base64, hex

From what I am told, I have a base64 encoded string. It has the following form:

```
"abcd..ef\0\0\0\0..\0"
```

It is the first time that I see base64 having '\0'. What does it mean? I don't think it is even a valid base64 character. However, ASCII to base64 gives me "=", which is padding. Maybe I have misunderstood something?

Comment: We need more context. `\0` is usually null bytes, which usually means end of string. I think it's safe to ignore with the current context you've laid out.

Comment: I get this data in a JSON response and it was encrypted before encoded into base64. Problem is that when I ignore \0, the length of the supposed base64 string is not enough